Why do commercial jets fly so high?
Everyone ever heard of a plane knows they usually go quite high into the atmosphere. To my knowledge, this is to help the plane go faster in low atmospheric densities and reduce aerodynamic drag. But is there any other reason for this? I feel there must be a few more as high altitude flights require pressure maintenance and much more powerful engines.

Could you be a bit more specific about what sorts of "other reasons" you have in mind, or why you think there should be some? As it stands, this doesn't sound like a very interesting question because it already contains the obvious answer.

Another aspect is that two engine airliners need to be able to fly on one engine, which means they always have more than twice the minimum power for flight available. The speed of sound means they can’t use this power to fly faster, but they can use it to fly higher- this is part of why the 787 or 737 cruise way higher than the A340 or 747

@TooTea "but other than the better customer experience, the lower personnel costs, the cost savings on fuel, and the better environmental impact... what has high altitude ever done for us?" :-)

They fly that high because they're too heavy to fly any higher.

One of the main reasons to fly high has nothing to do with efficiency and everything with passenger comfort: flying above the weather. The majority of weather phenomena, especially turbulence, happens in the first few km of the atmosphere. By simply flying higher, the ride is much smoother. Additionally, deviations or even cancellations due to the weather are much reduced

I think predominantly it is about efficiency though. A Boeing 737 true airspeed (TAS) at ~15,000 ft is ~280 knots and at ~35,000 is ~500 knots. Furthermore, in the tropics, the troposphere (where the weather is) rises to levels higher than typical commercial aircraft can fly

@tedioustortoise The majority of flights are not in the tropics though. And the question specifically asked about reasons other than lower drag.

If it was cheaper to transport passengers in dry tumblers I imagine budget airlines would...

@tedioustortoise You have the cart before the horse. The cruising altitude is set, then the aircraft is designed to be most efficient at that altitude.

Unfortunately, this popular and selected answer is Wrong.  Airlines are a business that operates on surprisingly thin margins.  They operate in a way to save fuel.  If it was just about weather, they would fly lower (saving energy of climbing) on good weather days and only fly high when weather and turbulence required it -- only flying high enough to avoid that day's weather.  Instead they fly at 36kft because that is where the efficiency benefit from climbing stops.  They fly here every day to save fuel every day.

Yes there is another reason. During the cruise phase of the flight the aeroplane burns fuel and its weight reduces, and its lift must therefore reduce as well to maintain equilibrium. So should it now:

reduce its AngleOfAttack to reduce lift;
lower its speed to reduce drag and lift;
or gain altitude to fly in even thinner air?


Above graph is from this answer which contains more details on the topic. It would be most efficient for the aircraft to continuously gain altitude as the weight reduces, but the highways in the sky have assigned altitudes so for safety reasons the aeroplane ascends in steps.

The most important reason for commercial aircraft to fly high is fuel efficiency.
The thrust specific fuel consumption (TSFC) of jet engines scales with the square root of the temperature.  Colder air means the engine can have a larger   temperature increase before melting the engine.  That is thermodynamically good.
So,
$\mathrm{TSFC}=\mathrm{TSFC}_0\,\sqrt{\theta}$
Where
$\mathrm{TSFC}_0$ Is the sea level $\mathrm{TSFC}$.
and
$\theta\equiv \frac{T_{t,0}}{T_{sls}}$
$T_{t,0}$ is the total temperature at the ambient condition the aircraft is flying at.
$T_{sls}$ is the sea level standard temperature.
The standard atmosphere model says that the ambient temperature gets colder until 11km (36,089 ft).  At that point, the temperature remains approximately constant until very high up -- then it gets warmer again.
Consequently, there is a fuel efficiency benefit to flying at 36,000 ft -- but not really in going higher.  You will find that most commercial aircraft cruise right around this altitude (given considerations for weather and traffic).

I think that historical perspective is the easiest way to understand why flying higher was needed in the first place (other than efficiency as requested in the question).
The first commercial airliner with a pressurized cabin was the Boeing 307 Stratoliner. One of the first operators was Transcontinental & Western Air (T&WA) and the development of the aircraft was carried out closely with it.
"Donald Webb Tomlinson at T&WA carried out five years of high altitude flight research, with a Northrop Gamma and a Douglas DC-1, which helped determine that T&WA would need a four-engine airliner with a pressurized cabin. A ceiling of at least 16,000 ft (4,900 m) was required to avoid summertime "chop" over the Rocky Mountains, and to allow the aircraft to fly around the thunderstorms that can sometimes block mountain passes, which meant a pressurized cabin would be the most comfortable for passengers on long flights".
So the very first reason to fly higher was simply to give a smoother ride to the passenger when flying around mountains. Less turbulence also implied that the airplane could fly faster - the first thing to do upon encountering an area of turbulence is reducing speed: With a cruising speed of 220 mph (350 km/h) at 20,000 ft, the Sratoliner was faster than comparable airplanes of the same era.

Quoted text from Wikipedia
